# Can I suggest features to Apple?

Tags: apple-inc

Is there a place on the Apple website where I can suggest features for OSX/iOS to Apple?

*For example, I want to suggest that you can drag Launchpad folders to your Dock.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple maintains a [Product Feedback area on their website](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) for reporting feature requests and bugs from the general public. Here is the [OS X feedback page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).